# Interchange columns according to the value in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to interchange the columns according to the value corresponding to that id.

I have used `sort.index(level = 0, axis =0)`

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1000'], 'P1': [60], 'P2': [25], 'P3': [10], 'P4': [35]})
y = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1001'], 'P1': [40], 'P2': [30], 'P3': [15], 'P4': [55]})
x.sort_index(level = 0, axis = 0)
```

Actual Result:

```
id P1 P2 P3 P4

1000 60 25 10 35
```

Expected Result:

```
id   P1  P4  P2 P3

1000  60 35 25 10
```

Comment: x[['id','P1','P4','P2','P3']] would work..

Answer (score 0):

when i look at you data, I assume that the column 'id' would be you index by which you are appending the columns,so the best would first to set you index and them sort them by values using taking axis=1.the code would look like below.

```
x = x.set_index('id')
x.sort_values(by ='1000', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`axis=1` is used for sort per row, set `ascending=False` and `by=0` is the row index

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1000'], 'P1': [60], 'P2': [25], 'P3': [10], 'P4': [35]})
# change id column data type object to int64
x['id'] = x['id'].astype('int64')
print (x.sort_values(by=0, axis=1, ascending=False))
```

**O/P:**

```
     id  P1  P4  P2  P3
0  1000  60  35  25  10
```